# Using TikZ conditional statement?

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals

I'd like some help to make a conditional statement in LaTeX and TikZ work. In this M(non-)WE, I'd like the first, third and fifth dots to be larger:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\def\bigdot{5pt}
\def\littledot{1pt}
\begin{centering}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {0,...,5}{
      \draw (\x,0) circle ({int(\x/2)==0?\bigdot:\littledot});
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{centering}
\end{document}
```

What am I not understanding? Thanks for any help or advice.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome! Are you looking for `iseven`?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \def\bigdot{5pt}
   \def\littledot{1pt}
    \foreach \x in {0,...,5}{
      \draw (\x,0) circle [radius={iseven(\x)?\bigdot:\littledot}];
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In your code you are asking to make the circles for which `int(\x/2)` is zero big. These are the circles at `\x=0` and `\x=1`, and this is what you get. However, if you want to have "the first, third and fifth dots to be larger" in a list `{0,...,5}` then you can make the dots larger for which `\x` is even.

**ADDENDUM**: As for the *different* [question raised in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/543627/using-tikz-conditional-statement/543631?noredirect=1#comment1373255_543631), you can use `mod`, as [suggested by AlexG](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/543636/194703), or `Mod`, which always returns nonnegative values and helps you to avoid confusion (at least I occasionally wasted a lot of time because I was using `mod`). Both versions are described on p. 1033 of pgfmanual v3.1.5. As above, I prefer the non-deprecated syntax

```
 circle[radius=<radius>]
```

over the older, deprecated syntax

```
 circle(<radius>)
```

so the proposal for the question in the comments could be

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \path (0,0) node[circle,inner sep=5cm] (c){};
   \def\bigdot{5pt}
   \def\littledot{1pt}
    \foreach \x in {0,...,359}{
      \draw (c.\x) circle [radius={Mod(\x,5)==0?\bigdot:\littledot}];
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note also that if you use `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}` then `tikz` gets automatically loaded, so `\usepackage{tikz}` is unnecessary. Also, I generally do not really like `\def`s but if you want to use them, use them locally, i.e. inside the `tikzpicture`, as above. Yet personally I'd use something like

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={rsmall=1;rbig=5;}]
   \path (0,0) node[circle,inner sep=5cm] (c){};
    \foreach \x in {0,...,359}{
      \draw (c.\x) circle [radius={(Mod(\x,5)==0?rbig:rsmall)*1pt}];
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, no. I just picked every other dot for the MWE. In reality, I need every fifth dot larger in the range {0,...,359} for a compass circle.
Thanks so much for taking the time to answer, though.

Comment: @KevinZembower Well, I was trying to answer the question. You can use `\draw (\x,0) circle [radius={Mod(\x,5)==0?\bigdot:\littledot}];` for the "every fifth" case. (Note the upper case in `Mod` and the syntax `[radius={Mod(\x,5)==0?\bigdot:\littledot}]` instead of round parentheses.)

Comment: @KevinZembower Then you need the `mod` operator. See my answer.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I did do a dumb mistake with the () instead of the {}. Thanks. What's the differerence between Mod() and mod()?

Comment: @KevinZembower I added an explanation to an addendum of the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for the added comments and suggestions. They're really helpful.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat:  Trying to execute your second example gives the error:

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))

! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/5)', to which you passed 
'', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.10     }

Comment: The last example also gives a similar error.

Comment: @KevinZembower It compiles fine on my updated TeXLive 2020 installation with `pdflatex`, `lualatex` and `xelatex`. (Let me mention that your original code works fine in principle, you just picked an inappropriate condition for getting "he first, third and fifth dots to be larger". In order to answer the original question, one can use `iseven(\x)`, `mod(\x,2)==0` or `Mod(\x,2)==0` or `int(\x/2)==\x/2` and so on, but there was never a problem in implementing conditions in general. I tried to explain why the output of your code is the expected output.)

Comment: Interesting. I'm using Latex on a Linux system. It starts compiling with:

$ pdflatex \\nonstopmode\\input test3.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>

Comment: @KevinZembower Yes, it could well be that on a rather old version there are problems. Of course there are also reasons for the changes in preferred syntax and even how the pgf functions work. (I am not even sure when `Mod` was added.)  What do you get if you put `\message{I am using pgf version \pgfversion^^J}` in your document? (Regardless of these issues here I'd recommend updating your TeX installation, there have been some important changes, not only in Ti*k*Z. For instance, my friend AlexG has created a really stunning package called `ocgx2`.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: Output on my system is, "I am using pgf version 3.0.1a".

Comment: @KevinZembower Yes, that's a five years old version. I'd recommend an update.

Answer (score 2):

You certainly want the `mod(x,y)` (Modulo) operator:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\def\bigdot{5pt}
\def\littledot{1pt}
\begin{centering}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {0,...,5}{
      \draw (\x,0) circle ({mod(\x,2)==0?\bigdot:\littledot});
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{centering}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this might be it. I'll try it tomorrow morning in my real code, and if I can get it to work. I'll select your answer. However, I would still like to see a solution using (?:). For instance, in the range {1,...100}, make just the 7th circle large. Thanks for your efforts to help me.

Comment: This solution uses the `(?:)`syntax.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I was thinking of another example, for instance, if I wanted just the 7th dot big in the range {1,...,100}. Would this be just ({\x==7?\bigdot:\littledot})?

Comment: Yes, but the range should start with zero. Then, the first dot would be big, followed by 6 small dots, the next being big again and so on.